# Iterative code for segment tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, segment-tree

I wanted to code segment tree in c++ and wrote code query operation through recursion but it's slow and giving TLE. So, can Someone suggest and explain to code the following through iteration ,will be a great help.Thanks in advance.

following code computes gcd over a range

```
int getgcd(vector<int> T, int ss,int se, int L, int R, int index)
{
if (L <= ss && R >= se)
      return T[index];
if (se < L || ss > R)
      return 0;
int mid = ((ss+se)>>1);
      return __gcd(getgcd(T, ss, mid, L, R, index<<1),getgcd(T, mid+1, se, L, R, (index<<1)+1));
}
```

Here ,

**T**-segment Tree

**ss**-segment Start

**se**-segment end

**index**-current node of segment tree

**L**-Lower query bound

**R**-upper uery bound

Comment: When you used the debugger, which lines are causing the issue?

Comment: What are the input values that are causing the issue?

Comment: A web-search on translating tail-recursive algorithms to iterative algorithms would probably be a much bigger win for you in the long run than having someone do it for you.

Comment: values for se,ss,L,R, index can be upto 10^5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass a vector by value. It is copied every time you call this function. So the time complexity of your solution is O(n * log n) per query, not O(log n). Passing a vector by reference should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it iteratively notice that it is just a DFS with something extra.
You can easily perform iterative DFS using stack.